# Accept either 0 or number between a range in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

In asp.net web forms I have to validate number that can be either 0 (not empty, but zero) or it have to be between some range. Zero is acceptable in every case, but if not zero it have to be between range, for example 20 - 40.
I know that I can do this easily on the server, but if it is possible I prefer to use some of asp.net validators?

Comment: `if (i == 0 || (i < max && i > min))`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there is a RangeValidator control.

Comment: As @TeodorIvanov suggested, [RangeValidator Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt(v=vs.100).aspx) **and** RequiredFieldValidator (for "empty") - also noted in link - _"If the input control is empty, no validation functions are called and validation succeeds. Use a RequiredFieldValidator control to prevent the user from skipping an input control."_

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [RegularExpressionValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e(v=vs.71).aspx) control.  This will allow you to meet both the 0 and 20-40 range validation with a single control.

Also, you would also want to use [RequiredFieldValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h(VS.80).aspx) control to validate that the field was populated with a value.

I'm not great with Regular Expressions; but I used this regular expression (`^([0]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0])$`) with the `RegularExpressionValidator` control; and I think it's what you're looking for.

Just set the `ControlToValidate` property to be the input that you are validating; and set the `ValidationExpression` property to be your validation rule; and set your `Text` to be the error to display and you are good to go.

[image: regex validater properties]